# Azure Error Creating Data Sync Group

Tags: azure, synchronization, authorization, azure-sql-database

I am attempting to create a Data Sync group between two Azure SQL DBs (v.12.0.2000.8). I have Reader access to the Resource group that contains both DBs. Still, when trying to create the Sync Group I get a permissions error:

*...does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/locations/syncGroupOperationResults/read' over scope 'subscription'''*

I had a coworker with Owner access to the Resource Group try this and they got the same error.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions about trying some other way to sync data between these databases, but I already have backup plans in mind. I'd just like to get this particular method working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in data sync service. Microsoft product team is working on the fix now. Before the issue is fixed, you need subscription contributor permission to create a sync group.

Comment: Thanks @Wu Xiaochen. It looks like you just need Reader, not Contributor. I was given Reader role at the subscription level and it worked.